# GTests not showing in VS19 test explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I installed the Test Adapter for Google Test for Visual Studio.

Then I created a new Google Test Project in the same Solution as the Project I want to test.

The pre-constructed example shows up in the Test explorer and works fine. But when I try to include the declaration of a method I want to test and write a test case for that method the test is not showing up in the Test Explorer anymore.

test.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"    //#pragma once & #include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "../Server/header/server.h"

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) 
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
    //EXPECT_EQ(Multiply(3, 5), 15);
}
```

server.h

```
#pragma once

int Multiply(int a, int b);
```

server.cpp

```
#include "../header/server.h"

int Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

The code above works until I uncomment the line *EXPECT_EQ(Multiply(3, 5), 15);*. After rebuilding the Test will not show up anymore in the Test explorer...

Server is configured as static library, the test project as application.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late of a response, but after struggling with trying to get GoogleTest working with my own project i came across this question.

For anyone reading this, you need to check the "Tests" dropdown/section in the Output window to view the test execution errors that might be being logged

(also this view does not self-clear like "Debug", or "Build" with each new run - pay attention to the timestamps)